# SQL deduct one month from a date but keep the order correct

Tags: sql, sql-server

The title is probably worded poorly but what I want to have is say I do this

```
SELECT DATEADD(month,-1,'4/30/2019')
```

Instead of getting 3/30/2019 I want 3/31/2019, how do we do this?

Comment: If 2012+    EOMonth(DATEADD(month,-1,'4/30/2019'))

Comment: Do you want the last day of the previous month?

Comment: @forpas Yes, I do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the last day of the previous month:

```
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, '2019-04-30'), -1)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d641f6a9a10016c47506d585b1f7810e).
Result:

```
2019-03-31
```